# map unknown properties with json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

im working with the lib: [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
i have a json file with the data below

```
{
"Product": 
  {
    "random Key1": "some text",
    "random Key2": "some text",
    "random Key3": "some text"
  },
"TestSequence":
 {
    "random Key4": "Some text"
 }
}
```

i can deserialize the json file but i can't map json properties to a class properties

```
 public class Product
    {
        [JsonExtensionData]
        private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData { get; set; }
    }
   public class MyData
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
    ------main programme ----
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"\Base File\Base.json"))
        {
            json = r.ReadToEnd();
            MyData invoice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);

            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoice);
        }
```

how can i access the value of "random Key1" property in my code?

Comment: deserialize to a dictionary (the property names will become keys) or implement a custom converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use a normal dictionary:

```
public class MyData
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Product { get; set; }
}
```

and then once you deserialize you could loop through all the keys and values:

```
var invoice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
foreach (var item in invoice.Product)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Of course in order to access a value directly you could need to know the key which is how dictionaries work:

```
Console.WriteLine(invoice.Product["random Key2"]);
```